# Infant and a lazy eye: Should I be concerned?

Tags: infant, health

Our son is about 3 months old. As he's starting to become a little more alert, I notice that his right eye isn't always tracking with his left. Obviously he will have to see an optometrist eventually for a check up somewhere down the road. At the moment though, since he's so young, is this something we should be concerned about?

Comment: Also, see a doctor.  You're probably going in to talk to one regularly anyway as your child gets older.  Ask them the next time you go in (or if that wont be for a while, make an appointment sooner).  Worst case they tell you it's normal.  Best case, you catch something early and can get it fixed before it's too late.  We [aren't supposed to ask or answer medical questions here](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because we aren't doctors (and even if some of us are, it would be extremely unprofessional to answer here other than to say "see a doctor/specialist").

Comment: See [related meta post](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/670/are-questions-about-generic-medical-fundamental-medical-information-on-topic).

Answer (score 5):

As someone who was diagnosed at age 2, and has lived with a lazy eye her whole life, (my parents couldn't afford the treatment,) I implore you to take your son to see an optometrist. The earlier it is detected, the easier it is to treat. The doctor will be able to advise you on the best course of action and time frame.

Comment: Also, just in case you're in the situation of "can't afford it" (and I've been there plenty,) know that (in my case) lazy eye isn't a huge issue when you get older on a day-to-day basis. It can cause social problems, (people feel uncomfortable looking you in the eye,) and I have to get a note from my eye doctor because I cannot pass an eye exam for my driver's license.  It didn't affect my ability to read, (I was an early reader actually,) and didn't affect my aptitude in school. That said, if you can get it checked out, please do so. :)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.babycenter.com/0_strabismus-and-amblyopia_10890.bc
http://www.aapos.org/terms/conditions/21

The answer seems pretty clear: it's normal for newborns, but since this has continued to 3 months, you should definitely ask your doctor.

"Fortunately, these conditions can be successfully treated if detected early."

I've knew a kindergarten-age kid who had a patch over one eye, and I've seen babies with the same.  It could also be an indication of other vision problems like farsightedness (in which case glasses could solve it), or it could be a problem in the tendons or muscles that could require surgery.  Or at this age it could still just go away by itself.  I personally wouldn't worry too much -- IF this is a problem, you're already ahead of the curve.

Answer (score 0):

See an optometrist. Our son had a similar condition and the younger you start treating it the better. He just had to wear an eye patch for 15 minutes a day for a few months. He hated it at first, but in a couple of days he was playing as normal and didn't notice the patch at all after we put it on.